# Optimizing a Join

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have a join that looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN abc__emails.my208 my3 
   ON my3.eid = my.eid 
   AND (
         my3.my_id = 417 
         AND my3.data = 'AB Deleted Account'
   )
```

This query is bordeline runnable. I'm trying to save every scrap of memory. My question then:

```
LEFT JOIN abc__emails.my208 my3 
   ON my3.eid = my.eid 
   AND my3.data = 'AB Deleted Account'
```

I removed the `my3.my_id = 417` part.

Records where my_id = 417 include 'AB Deleted Account' but also a couple of other strings. I included it because I'm thinking I may help SQL narrow it down. Is that wrong?

I really just want the join to be on records where `my3.data = 'AB Deleted Account'.`

Is it best to add on as many "filters" as possible or to remove as many as possible?

eid is already the key on both tables.

**Following feedback here is the output of EXPLAIN**

```
1   SIMPLE  co  ALL                 198784  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  my  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   abc_emails.co.id,const  1   
1   SIMPLE  my1 eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   abc_emails.my.eid,const 1   
1   SIMPLE  my2 eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   abc_emails.my.eid,const 1   
1   SIMPLE  my3 ref ver_eid ver_eid 4   abc_emails.my.eid   246 
1   SIMPLE  i   ref eid_iid eid_iid 10  abc_emails.my.eid,const 1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  nvk eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   abc_emails.co.id    1
```

**And here is the query itself**

```
SELECT
    co.id AS ID_Eid,
    co.email,
    def.def_medium AS def_Medium_def208,
    co.created AS Contact_Create_Date,
    my1.data AS PAW_ID,
    my.data AS Trial_Date,
    my2.data AS Upgrade_Date,
    MIN(my3.lastmod) AS Cancel_Date
FROM 
    abc_emails.cid208 co
LEFT JOIN abc_emails.my208 my ON my.eid = co.id AND my.my_id = 581
LEFT JOIN abc_emails.my208 my1 ON my1.eid = my.eid AND my1.my_id = 2765 
LEFT JOIN abc_emails.my208 my2 ON my2.eid = my.eid AND my2.my_id = 3347 
LEFT JOIN abc__emails.my208 my3 ON my3.eid = my.eid AND (my3.my_id = 417 AND my3.data = 'AB Deleted Account') 
LEFT JOIN abc_emails.i208 i ON i.eid = my.eid AND i.iid = 22467
LEFT JOIN abc_emails.def208 def ON def.eid = co.id
WHERE i.iid IS NULL
GROUP BY ID_Eid, email, def_Medium_def208, Contact_Create_Date, PAW_ID, Upgrade_Date
```

Comment: Depends a lot on the query. Are the other columns indexed ? That would reduce the amount that is needed to search though for example. Look at the EXPLAIN and see how many rows are looked at

Comment: Indeed, we need `CREATE TABLE` & `EXPLAIN` information. Keep in mind that _usually_ (there are exceptions), MySQL will only use one key, so if you often query on an `ied` **and** `my_id` together, having a compound key spanning both of them would help in selects (but: every extra index hurts modification performance).

Comment: You can't optimize just a given clause. **We need to see the entire query and table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, see http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: You left joined something. What left join does is join records and if no match is found - it adds a null record onto it. Your query shows that it inspects 198,784 records in the table aliased by `co`. You just showed us the join, without the remainder. That means you are looking at the **wrong** place. As others have commented, giving out a part of the query, without any definitions nor table engine in question is simply not enough to analyse this further.

Comment: Query added now. Apologies. I didn't want to just dump a query and the explain statement and say "Here, fix this". I was initially trying to determine if there was anything I could do to a join specifically to optimize the query. Perhaps I shouldn't have isolated that part alone.

Comment: That query selects everything from `abc_emails.cid208` table, there's no restricting factor. Now comes the part where you tell us why you need so much data? Do you need all ~200k rows?

Comment: @N.B. the results of this query will be used in a dashboard. It is more data than I'd typically pull out of a db for use in excel but this particular dashboard is a database summary of all users and we want all key data points associated with them: create date, purchase dates etc. So in this instance we really need it all. I was thinking of maybe pulling 5o or 100k records at a time. I imagine that's possible?

Comment: If you want it to work faster, you need to avoid disk seek and disk I/O. That's achieved by using InnoDB and allocating as much RAM as possible via `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. That's the only way you can achieve efficiency, so you can't spare any memory.